# compute complex laplacian using computer program

Tags: complex-analysis, laplacian, computer-algebra-systems

I want to compute the laplacian of some complicate function, for example $|f''(z) + f'(z)\frac{1}{1-|f|^2}|\frac{1-|z|^2}{1-|f|^2}$ assuming $f$ is smooth and then evaluate it at $0$. I wonder whether there is some computer software that can help me with this.

We know that laplacian $\Delta$ is just multiples of $\partial_{\bar z z}$, then one approach would just be that denote the conjugate of $f(x)$ by $g(y)$, and then ask wolfram alpha to compute $\partial_{y x}$, this works out fine if we only have some simple functions, when the function becomes a little bit more complex, wolfram alpha will not give you any output.

One problem with matlab is that you have to specify the function.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider looking at [MatLab](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html). I know they have a [free trial](https://www.mathworks.com/programs/trials/trial_request.html?ref=ggl&s_eid=ppc_29850095842&q=matlab) that you could use to try it out. I have never tried though so I'm sorry if this doesn't help.

Comment: can matlab do symbolic differentiation? I cannot find anything relevant to it online.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/diff.html) help? I'm not very familiar with the software so I would recommend searching the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/) on their site.